# to find locations in google map within 5 km radius of a given point

Tags: google-maps

hey i just want to gather the locations in google maps database  which are under 5 km radius of the given point.. i will be storing them in database for later processing .....can this be done...thanks...how to get longitude and latitude of points with in the required circle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PlaceSearches](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches)
with the parameter : `radius`

Comment: That's now a 404 Not Found