# I am trying to develop a property website

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to develop a property website that and looking for a mapping facility that allows the user to submit a query whether it be postcode or place name and the results to come back with all the listings in that area along with a map - similar to all other property search sites.
I also need the facility to widen the search by 1 mile, 2, 3, 5 etc

Is this possible with the standard integration of google maps or do I need to map the individual boundries.
Also is this a cost effective solution if I were to receive 10,000 queries on the site a day

Comment: Have you got a database of properties?

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to perform the property search on your server and not load all properties on a Google Map for searching. By storing the latitude/longitude of each property in your database, you can perform the search and then return the results by displaying them on a map.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary requirement is to first check the location based on radius:

(Assume: the location is valid with a state and a country)

You can use place searches, to find the locations as mentioned in this link [StakOverflow: find locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300375/to-find-locations-in-google-map-within-5-km-radius-of-a-given-point)  !

In this you can use https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=fr to get the list of place searches